# What's the condition for the intensity of the interference of light to be zero?

Tags: optics

I need to solve this question:

> "Suppose light comes from a medium $n_1$, refract a part of it in a medium of index $n_2$. Below the $n_2$ material, there is a $n_3$ material with refractive index greater than $n_2$. So there occurs part of reflection and part of refraction. What is the condition that needs to be satisfied if we want that the intensity of the reflected light be zero?"
> (The incidence is perpendicular, $n_3>n_2>n_1$.)

I got the right answer which is $n_2= \sqrt{n_1 n_3}$. The problem is that I am not sure why this is right.

To get this answer, intuitively I thought that the reflection coefficients of intensity should be equal, to cancel. That is, let $r_{ij}=(\frac{n_2- n_3}{n_i+ n_j})^2$. So the condition is $r_{12}=r_{23}$.

But, in fact, I have no idea why this is right.
See:

The first electric field incides at the intersection 12. So, $E_{ref} = -RE, E_{trans} = TE$. The transmitted electric fields incides at intersection 23, and the reflected field is $E_{ref} = -R'TE$. This reflected fields incides at 12 and got transmitted with amplitude $E = -R'TTE$.

So, summarising, we have, at the end:
$$E = -ER - ET^2R'e^{ikn_{2}d}$$

To get the intensity equal to zero, $|E|*|E| = 0$.

This is equivalent to $$R²+T^4R'^2 + 2RT^2R'cos(2kn_2d)$$

Now, if we substitute the answer here, it will not be zero.   Honestly, I am not sure what is wrong.

I would appreciate if you help me to understand why $n_2= \sqrt{n_1 n_3}$ makes the intensity zero. In other words, how to get $r_{12}=r_{23}$ by some algebra, and not by mere intuition?

Also, where is the error in my second attempt? I think maybe the error is that it should, in fact, have a progression geometric in T. But not sure about that.

thx

Comment: *What is the condition that needs to be satisfied if we want that the intensity of the reflected light be zero?* As you have shown it is impossible.  The intensity of the reflected light can be reduced but not made zero.

Comment: Maybe having a look at the Fresnel Equations could help your understanding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations

Answer (score 1):

You started correctly, but have to sum up over infinite times of reflections,  transmissions etc., which leads to series expression. Then you have to find for the phase a destructive condition $d=(2m+1)\frac{\lambda_1}{4}$.

Next, for optimal performance (not to gain destructive intereference), you must demand the equality of the reflectance R12 = R23 = $\vert{\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}}\vert^2 =\vert{\frac{n_2-n_3}{n_2+n_3}}\vert^2$ which gives $n_2=\sqrt{n_1n_3}$ .

Remember light flux is proportional to the square of the electric field amplitude